# find the sql connectionstring from a vb.net application

Tags: sql, vb.net, connection-string

i have visual studio 2008 in with i'm doing an ASP.NET application.
Now i want to link my pages to SQL Server 2008. On my page default.aspx, I put a gridview and then i can find the connection string from there to the sql server db, which i can then put in a class and have all pages use it.
Is this the only way to find the connection string for any servers on the network or are there other ways (probably better ways of finding the conn string?)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a gridview, you can use the WebConfigurationManager in 2008...

Here's a code sample from MSDN that shows this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="NorthwindConnectionString" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here's the VB.Net code that uses this connection string.

```
Dim rootWebConfig As System.Configuration.Configuration
    rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot")
Dim connString As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings
If (0 < rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count) Then
    connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings("NorthwindConnectionString")
    If Not (connString.ConnectionString = Nothing) Then
        Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = {0}", connString.ConnectionString)
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string")
    End If
End If
```

Comment: But how does the web.config know which database i'm using? the connectionstring data source only gives "Server Name". If i change that name, what about username and password?

Comment: data source is the server and instance name, and initial catalog is your database name.

Comment: I'm sorry. that's what i meant. how does id and password work there? I'm asking because I have to work on someone's project on their DB and computer. If i use gridview i dont need to ask them username and password. With this method do i need username/password or does it come in the web.config?

Comment: Are you asking if you will have to prompt the user for the username and password?  The gridview is probably just using an existing connection string in your web.config, so it will have access to the same data that is used by the WebConfigurationManager... I'd look at the web.config and see what your connection string looks like...

Comment: o ok. So whatever is in the web.config is what i should use. In case of username and password, the webconfiguration manager will take care of that. right? no prompts for username/password

Comment: Basically when something wants to talk to the database, it needs a connection string to tell it where to go, what database to use, and what username / password to use.  This is typically stored in your web.config file.  Your gridview just grabs that connection string automatically, but if you want to talk to the database in other ways, you can use the WebConfigurationManager to grab that connection string from your web.config for other purposes.  Your user should never be prompted for a SQL username / password... that's hidden internals of your application.

Comment: perfect. thank you so much for your help. One last question. Is one method better than the other? like security wise? Cause i know using gridview i put the conn string in a class file and make it like Private Const SqlCnnStr As String = "data source=;user id=;password=;initial catalog=;Connect Timeout=30".. So since this is open is it considered bad programming or both have same security issues?

Comment: Well... the reason for putting it in the web.config is so that you can easily change the value.  You'll point to a different database in testing that you do when you are in production.  If you have it in a class, then you have to recompile your code when you move between environments.  In either case, the username / password would exist on your server, either in the DLL, or in the web.config... so putting it in a class doesn't secure it. You can use "aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf “connectionStrings”" to encrypt the data in your web.config.  If this is helpful, please upvote and accept my answer. :-)